# Does ssh command intercept a remote host before it executes .bashrc?

Tags: bash, ssh

If there is a host, which modifies `.bashrc`, so that it immediately logout users who login with SSH.

If I login to the remote host by entering a command like:

```
ssh user@hostname bash
```

then, does the `bash`, which is next to the `user@hostname`, executed before the `.bashrc` file or even ignore it?

I tried with that command, and was possible to access to the host. It was quite different with a normal terminal because there was nothing other than a blinking cursor, but was able to run serveral linux commands, and even it was possible to see a contents inside txt files via `cat` command.

But, when I entered like:

```
ssh -t user@hostname bash
```

the connection automatically closed down.

I can’t explain, precisely, what is happening under the hood and the mechanism of `-t` option with `bash`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[What is an interactive shell?](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/What-is-an-Interactive-Shell_003f.html)

> An interactive shell is one started without non-option arguments (unless -s is specified) and without specifying the -c option, whose input and error output are both connected to terminals (as determined by isatty(3)), or one started with the -i option.

[Startup Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html):

> When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, Bash reads and executes commands from ~/.bashrc, if that file exists. This may be inhibited by using the --norc option. The --rcfile file option will force Bash to read and execute commands from file instead of ~/.bashrc.

In short, allocating a pseudo-tty with the `-t` option satisfies the requirement that `input and error output are both connected to terminals (as determiend by isatty(3))` to cause bash to be invoked in interactive mode. Interactive shells read the .bashrc file which contains your undesired line.

You can make the bash shell read something else with `--rcfile` or ignore the file entire with `--norc`, although there isn't a guarantee that another startup file won't independently read bashrc itself.

Comment: So, you mean without -t option(ssh user@hostname bash), it becomes non-interactive shells so that it doesn't execute .bashrc file. Is that right?

Comment: Yes. You can test this by logging in with `ssh user@hostname bash` and then running `echo $-` in the shell. Interactive shells will have `i` in the option flag list while non-interactive shells will not have it.

Comment: Yeah, it really doesn't have a letter `i`. Thanks a lot.